# Can someone help me to find boundary points of this set?

Tags: general-topology

(0,1) $\cup$ (1,2)
I solved it and I found that boundary points is {0,2}, but I am not sure for {1}. Can I put {1} in boundary points ? Shall you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $1$ is indeed in the boundary: any open interval around $1$ contains $1$ (which is in the complement) and points $1+r$ for small $r$ which lie in the set.

Alternatively: $A= (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ is open (a union of open intervals), its closure is $[0,2]$ and so the boundary, the set difference of these is $\{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

New edit : I misread the set , totally right.

Yes 1 will also be in the boundary because any open set containing $1$ contains a ball around it , and it will intersect $1$, since it lies inside the ball , and the set .

So the boundary is $\{0,1,2\}.$

Comment: That ball *does* intersect the complement, namely in $1$!